# Category layered navigation include searchable products

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I have a Magento (1.9.2.1) store I am working on where I have few categories (just 10), but each category has 1000's of single products. I only want a selection  of products (sort of featured but more of a selection) to display on any category page by default, but if the user then uses the layered navigation to filter down the products, then it will include all the products in that category as criteria are applied.
My first approach was the single product visibility setting choices of "catalog,search" and "search" but the layered navigation will only include the items which are marked as "catalog" or "catalog,search".
I need the layered navigation (including it's product count) to include everything in the category.
Does anyone know if it is possible (without a core hack) to get the layered navigation to include items which have a visibility set to "search" within that category? Or an alternative way of achieving this?
Any extension suggestions would also be welcome!

Comment: This is not a native functionality and what you're asking is quite broad. It's probable possible, even without a core hack which I would strongly recommend NOT to do. You can probably fix it by using the search results page in some way. But again, it would take quite some work and make sure it's done correctly without corehacks

Comment: Thanks Sander Mangel, I am avoiding core hacks like the plague and will find a complete alternative method for the display if I don't find a solution. It's a broad request, I suppose I am asking magento for a "search,layered navigation" visibility setting for products that is not visible in the default catalog with no layered navigation set. I have never encountered a situation like this in any store I've seen or worked on, and will probably resort to the category product sort order if this is too tricky.

Comment: You could probably do something with the getLoadedProductCollection where you add a limit on the retrieved collection if no filters are set and perhaps an extra attributeToFilter that searches for something like 'featured'

Comment: Thanks Sander Mangel, I have had a play with that idea but in the long term management of the site it would get a little complex. I've gone with a simpler answer and revert to a static block for the category page. A good nights sleep and a different approach idea helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you change your category display mode from products to static block only. You can then create a static block that loads a custom template that displays a defined selection of products from the category the way you want.

Your filtered navigation will still work on all products.

This is fairly easy to achieve if you have some Magento development experience.

Comment: Thanks! Too much thought does not help sometimes when the answer is a simpler/alternative approach. Issue solved.